# Analytic function taking values $1/2, 1/2, 1/4, 1/4, 1/6, 1/6, …$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following exercise from Richard Silverman's *Introductory Complex Analysis* book (page 210, Problem 5).

> Does there exist a function which is analytic at the point $z=0$ and
>   takes the following values at the points $z=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n=1, 2,
>  3, …$:
>
> a) $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, … $
>
> b) $0, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{6}, 0,  …, 0, \frac{1}{2k}, ...$
>
> c) $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{6},
>  \frac{1}{6}, …, \frac{1}{2k}, \frac{1}{2k}, ...$
>
> d) $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{5}{6},
> \frac{6}{7}, …, \frac{k}{k+1}, ...$

For part a), it is clear that no such analytic function exists since it wouldn't even be continuous at $z=0$. For part d), I believe the function $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z+1}$ satisfies the desired condition.

I would very much appreciate some help on parts b) and c). I think one needs to use uniqueness principle of analytic functions, which states that if two analytic functions agree on a sequence of distinct points with accumulation point in the domain, then they are equal. But I don't see how one can apply this theorem in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b) and c) are of the same type and you can use the uniqeuness principle. Consider even $n=2k$ and odd $n=2k-1$ separately: For b), which analytic functions are there such that $f(\frac1{2k-1})=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$? And which have $f(\frac1{2k})=\frac1{2k}$  for all $k\in\mathbb N$? (In fact, this method would work also for part a)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay so for part b), are you saying that I should find an analytic function $f$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)=0$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\frac{1}{2k}$ are satisfied _simulatenously_ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$? I cannot think of such an analytic function.

Comment: @Prism, no the two forms are for parts b and c respectively.

Comment: @guest: Thanks. So for part (c), the function $g(z)=z$ has the property that $g\left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\frac{1}{2k}$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Such a function $f(z)$ would have to agree with $g(z)=z$ on the sequence $z_k=\frac{1}{2k}$ which has a limit point $0$. By uniqueness, it would follow that $f(z)=z$ which contradicts $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Exactly; the same reasoning gives b.  The function for b is even easier to find :)

Comment: @guest: Right, it is just $g(z)=0$. :) Thanks a lot for the guidance!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, so for (a), you want to start out with $f\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right) = 0$ again, and then your function is also $g(z)=0$, which contradicts the fact that $f(1)=1$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, not sure how to tag you.

Comment: @guest, or you could answer my question, too.